# Aggregate Function in LINQ expression throws error. (cannot be translated into a store expression.)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, aggregate-functions

Error:
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Aggregate[String,String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.String, System.Func`3[System.String,System.String,System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Linq Expression:

```
      Items = context.TESTANSWER.Where(x => x.ID == 6729223232)
            .Join(context.QUESTIONREPOs, x => x.QUESTIONID, y => y.ID, (x, y) => new { x = x, y = y })
            .Join(context.OPTIONREPOs, p => p.x.QUESTIONID, q => q.QUESTIONID, (p, q) => new { p = p, q = q }).Where(p => p.p.x.RESPONSEID == p.q.ID)
            .GroupJoin(context.TESTANSWERASSOCIATION, c => c.p.x.ID, b => b.TESTANSWERID, (c, b) => new { c = c, b = b })
            .SelectMany(
                n => n.b.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                    (n, b) =>
                        new QuestListItemObj
                        {
                            State = n.c.p.x.STATE,
                            Association = n.b.Select(l => l.ASSOCIATION.TITLE).ToList().Aggregate((s, t) => s + ", " + t),
                            Description = n.c.p.y.DESCRIPTION,
                            Question = n.c.p.y.QUESTION,
                            Answer = n.c.q.OPTIONTEXT,
                        }).ToList();
```

I also just tried SelectMany but got same error..

```
 Affiliaiton = n.b.SelectMany(l => l.AFFILIATION.TITLE).Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, t) => s + ", " + t),
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're having an `IQueryable` that translates to SQL. Your `Aggregate` is a method that is unknown to SQL, so there is no way to translate it and you get your exception.

A possible way is to call `AsEnumerable()` before. This will cause the query to execute and get the data from your SQL server, and the remaining actions are executed in memory (and not on your SQL Server).

```
myQuery.AsEnumerable().Aggregate(...)
```

Answer (score 4):

As the error message is telling you, the database doesn't know how to translate that code into SQL.

Fortunately, there really isn't any need for it to do so.  Rather than putting the data into a comma delimited string on the DB end, just pull down the pieces and make a string out of it in C#.  It's pulling the same amount of data, so there's no real reason to use a database.

You can use `AsEnumerable` to ensure that the following operation is one in linq to object, not on the DB end, but in this case `Aggreagte` is a poor tool to use for appending values to a string.  Just use `String.Join`.

```
var query = n.b.SelectMany(l => l.AFFILIATION.TITLE);


//not very efficient option, but will work
string data1 = query.AsEnumerable().
    .Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, t) => s + ", " + t);

//faster, more efficient, simpler to write, and clearer to the reader.
string data2 = string.Join(", ", query);
```